# How JVM works internally

Tags: java, security

ALL,

At work we have a software written in JAVA. It is operational and works fine. In couple of sources we have a statements like this:

```
import x.y.z
```

There is no source file where we use

```
import x.y.*
```

Recently we had a scan from the Software Assurance team and they found couple of deficiencies.

An example would be this:

```
The code is using MD5 encryption algorithm.
```

Our code does not even import a class connected to the MD5 let alone use it.

So, my question would be:

If I have an import for the class Foo, does JVM actually pulls everything from the JAR/library ?

Thank you.

Comment: import only is used on compile time so you can write `z` instead of `x.y.z` each time you need class `z`, that is, without having to use the fully qualified name - it is kind of importing the namespace. The generated code is the same if you use the import or the fully qualified name without the import. Anyway, ask the "Software Assurance team" for more details of where/what the problem is.

Comment: I suspect what you are encountering is one of the JVM parameters.  Not necessarily the actual code.

Comment: You will not necessarily find a class named `MD5something` or similar. Most probably the code is using JCE and then the code will look like `mac = Mac.getInstance("MD5");result = mac.doFinal(bytes)`.

Comment: Note that none of your questions actually ask how the JVM works internally.  They are how the language works, or how to fix my static analysis tool warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I have an import for the class Foo, does JVM actually pulls everything from the JAR/library ?

No.  Only the classes that are needed *at runtime* will be loaded by the JVM.

However, if your class `A` uses library class `L1`, and class `L1` uses another library class `L2`, then *both* `L1` and `L2` will be loaded.  Thus you cannot determine if MD5 is used simply by looking at your classes `import` statements.  (There are other reasons too ...)

One way to determine the classes that are actually used is to start the JVM with the command line option `-verbose:class`.  This displays info about each loaded class, including library classes.

Comment: thank you. We will try to run with `-verbose` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

First, java compiler compiles the source code into byte code. At the run time,Java Virtual Machine (JVM) interprets this byte code and generates machine code which will be directly executed by the machine in which java program runs.

Visit good tutorial of JVM,JRE and JDK https://javatutorialdetails.blogspot.com/2017/10/java-tutorial-in-details-step-by-step.html